# Can we use DC-DC Buck convert installed 3.8v battery to power Phone continuously?

Tags: batteries, current, dc, dc-dc-converter, converter

I have a Windows tablet whose battery is dead and I want to convert it to without battery to use as a digital photo frame.

Table dead battery is 3.8V

Can I use DC-DC Buck convert (DC-DC converter step-down 1.23-30V 1.5A)  with input 5V regular mobile charger to power this tablet? 
What about Current is it enough?

Full specs of converter:-
Input voltage: 4 – 35VDC
* Output voltage: 1.23 – 30VDC
* Max current: 3A (1.5A continuous)
* Maximum efficiency: 90%

Answer (score 0):

It may not be enough, depending on what you are doing on the tablet. It may try to pull more current than just 1.5A. And the tablet may need the battery sensor connection, as its not just power and ground. Some devices are finicky about that (for example, a Mifi 7700 hotspot).

You can certainly try it to see if it will run or not.